# Solve Compile error in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I keep getting errors such as `error:atrribute paddingleft` not found and failed linking file resources errors and a few other does anyone know the solution to my problem in my main.java class I have it set as   `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.issacrodriguez.robber.main">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scoreLabel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingleft="10dp"
        android:text="Score : 300"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/StartLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tap To Start!"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="130dp" />

       <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/robber"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/robberr"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

       <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/moneybag"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/moneybag" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cop"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cop"/>

    </FrameLayout>




</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Android Studio**

Comment: error in `@+id/scoreLabel ID`, 1. wrong attribute name (paddingleft) and 2. wrote twice with mistake (paddingLeft).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you are doing Wrong-:

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/scoreLabel"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="50dp"
     android:gravity="center_vertical"
     android:paddingLeft="50dp"
     android:text="Score : 300"
     android:textSize="18sp" />
```

We have only `android:paddingLeft="50dp"` in android not something like
`android:paddingleft="10dp"` remove this it will compile then.